# Geometric interpretation of $\partial/\partial z$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

My understanding is that analytic derivative ,$\partial\phi/\partial z$, and anti-analytic derivative ,$\partial\phi/\partial\bar{z}$, are resp. tangent and normal to the curve $\phi$. Am i right?can you enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. Assuming you mean that the curve is given by the equation $\phi(x,y)=0$, where $\phi$ is some real valued function in the plane... then the gradient, $\nabla\phi=(\phi_x, \phi_y)$, is normal to the curve. This can be rewritten in complex notation as $\phi_x+i\phi_y$, which is, by definion, $2\partial\phi/\partial\bar{z}.$ Now $\partial\phi/\partial {z}$ is one half the conjugate  of the former, which is not tangent to the curve in general. If you want a tangent vector, just rotate the normal by 90 degrees, i.e. muliply by $i$, so $i\partial\phi/\partial\bar{z}$ would give a vector tangent to the curve.

Comment: Yeah perhaps i should have taken multyplying by two into account.not a big deal.and curve is given by equating to zero.thanks for your answer.perfectly makea sense.